# Accesses specific element of array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access a specific entry of an array. I'm passing in a string and I'm trying to parse it based on spaces. Is there an easier way to do this?

```
var toAdd = "Hello Everyone this is cool isnt it?";
var final = "";
var toAdd2 = [ ];
var sub = "";
var lastIndex = 0;

for( var i = 0; i < toAdd.length; i++ )
{
    if( toAdd[ i ] == " ")
    {
        sub = toAdd.substring( lastIndex , i ).trim();
        toAdd2[ i ] = sub;
        lastIndex = i;
    }

    if( i == toAdd.length - 1 )
    {
        sub = toAdd.substring( lastIndex, toAdd.length).trim();
        toAdd2[ i ] = sub;
    }
}

console.log( toAdd2[ 0 ] );
```

This keeps giving me an error saying,
    TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

Comment: It doesn't throw an error for me. It just logs `undefined`. But if you want to split the string into words, use `.split`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split.

Comment: For the sake of good practice do not use "sub" or "final" as the name of a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var str = "Hello Everyone this is cool isnt it?";
var toAdd = str.split(" ");
```

Comment: split(" ") function will return the array that contains every single word in your string. Ex toAdd[0] = Hello; toAdd[1] = Everyone;...

Answer (score 1):

There is a flaw in your algorithm. See the output of `console.log(toAdd2)`:

> [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, "Hello",
>   undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
>   undefined, undefined, "Everyone", undefined, undefined, undefined,
>   undefined, "this", undefined, undefined, "is", undefined, undefined,
>   undefined, undefined, "cool", undefined, undefined, undefined,
>   undefined, "isnt", undefined, undefined, "it?"]

Change it to:

```
if( toAdd[ i ] == " ")
{
    sub = toAdd.substring( lastIndex , i ).trim();
    toAdd2.push(sub);

    lastIndex = i;
}

if( i == toAdd.length - 1 )
{
    sub = toAdd.substring( lastIndex, toAdd.length).trim();
    toAdd2.push(sub);
}
```

Now it gets the proper output:

```
["Hello", "Everyone", "this", "is", "cool", "isnt", "it?"]
```

---

Before you were iterating over every character in `toAdd`, and only changing the indices that matched the condition. Therefore most of the elements in `toAdd2` would be unassigned and therefore undefined.  You want to use `array.push` to add an element to the array.

Comment: What exactly is the flaw? Why does your solution fixes it? Please don't just post code, also explain the problem/solution.